# can't load package: C:\Go\src\"application"\db.go:10:2: non-standard import "github.com/boltdb/bolt" in standard package "application"

Tags: go, gopath, bolt, boltdb

I'm new to coding so I'm sure my mistake is something simple.  I'm trying to install an application from github.com/benbjohnson/roommate.  I have installed go and am able to get the file.

```
go get github.com/boltdb/bolt/...
```

However, when I try to build the roommate file I get: "can't load package: C:\Go\src\roommate\db.go:10:2: non-standard import "github.com/boltdb/bolt" in standard package "roommate""

I have tried changing the GOPATH.
I have verified that my GOROOT and GOPATH are not the same.

My Go environment is:

```
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOCACHE=C:\Users\Jason\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOFLAGS=
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\Users\Jason\go-work
set GOPROXY=
set GORACE=
set GOROOT=C:\Go
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GCCGO=gccgo
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set GOMOD=
set CGO_CFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_FFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-g -O2
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=C:\Users\Jason\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build767006230=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches
```

Comment: You must not (really, never!) install 3rd party packages into your Go installation at C:/Go. Set up a workspace as explained in How to Write Go Code.

Comment: I do have a workspace setup.  It's reflected above in my GOPATH

Comment: No, the error specifically shows that you put `roommate` in your Go installation; `C:\Go\src\roommate\db.go`. Clean that out and put it in the correct location (which you can do with `go get` to avoid this situation in the first place)